# Template Function declared in header, defined in seperate .cpp file causing undefined reference error

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries, header-files, function-templates

So I've learnt that it's best to first declared function in header file, than define it in a seperate `.cpp` file as function definition within headers aren't recommended. And I did so, with normal function and it worked. but when I try to do the same thing with template functions, it gave back error like

```
/usr/sbin/ld: /tmp/cc196bnS.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `double d::numerical::test<double>(double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Following will be a minimal working example where in header file I've define a normal function `d::numerical::test2(double)` and a template function `template<typename T> d::numerical::test(T)`. Then `cout` their returning value individually in `test.cpp`. Compiled with `g++ integration.cpp test.cpp`, the one calling normal function `test2` compiled and ran successfully, yet if I change it to `test` it throws the error as shown above.

Notice I've also added a `const` and a class in the header file, and those can also be accessed to ensure that the file actually get included properly.

I've read online ([here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/439296/template-function-in-header-file)) that it seems template functions' definition must also be in header file? But doesn't that goes against the rule that don't define function in header? What is the proper solution for these cases?

---

### MWE

`test.cpp`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include"./integration.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << d::numerical::test(1.) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`integration.hpp`

```
#ifndef __FUNC_NUM_INTE__
#define __FUNC_NUM_INTE__
namespace d { namespace numerical {
    const double EPS=1e-24;
    double test2(double);
    template<typename T> double test(T);
    template<typename T>
        class dp {
            T odd, even;
        };
}}
#endif
```

`integration.cpp`

```
#include"integration.hpp"

double d::numerical::test2(double x) {
    return x;
}

template<typename T>
double d::numerical::test(T x) {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: The short and simple answer is to put the definition of the template in the header. The alternative is (in the same source file where you define the function template) to explicitly instantiate the template over every type for which it ever gets used.

Comment: @JerryCoffin So what I learnt is that, if you define function within header, and that header is included multiple times throughout the project, you might have multiple copies of that function which will break the linker. Then in this circumstance, is it a) defining template function within header won't cause such issue, or b) defining template function within header **then explicitly instantiate it in .cpp file** would prevent such issue?

Comment: When you define the function in the header, you want to to mark it as `inline` to prevent problems from multiple definitions. Yes, explicit instantiation in the cpp file will do the same (but it's more work).

Comment: @JerryCoffin then will the explicit instantiation method prevents disadvantages for `inline` functions such as possibility of code-bloat and longer compilation time as listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only)?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you define `test2` with `double` type in `.cpp` file, but not `test` method (without `2` in name).

Did you expect the compiler to define it automatically?

Then, you should move the template definition to header, I mean the part:

```
template<typename T>
double d::numerical::test(T x) {
    return x;
}
```

> **Note** that templates are a compile time feature, and if your method needs to accept multiple types as input (without being in a header), then research for `variant` (or `QVariant` which is part of Qt framework).